# Simple javascript console log (FireFox)

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying to log the change of a value in the console (Firefox/Firefly, mac).

```
 if(count < 1000)
 {
  count = count+1;
  console.log(count);
  setTimeout("startProgress", 1000);
 }
```

This is only returning the value 1.  It stops after that.

Am I doing something wrong or is there something else affecting this?

Comment: You should not pass a string to `setTimeout`.

Comment: @SLaks: +1. Would be +(>1) if I could.

Comment: @SLaks: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Am I wrong?

Comment: yes, but not in the sense that strings don't work, just that they shouldn't be used.  `setTimeout(startProgress, 1000)` is more correct for many reasons, the largest being that it doesn't invoke the Javascript compiler.  It also solves the problem with your timer, which needs parens to work -- `setTimeout("startProgress()", 1000);`.

Comment: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/efficient-javascript/?page=2#timeouts

Comment: @KevinBrown avoid w3schools where possible.

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis, that's quite an unsupported, unhelpful, and uncertain comment.

Comment: @KevinBrown. You're quite right, I should have supported the comment: http://w3fools.com/ http://www.quora.com/In-what-way-is-W3Schools-com-a-good-resource-for-learning-HTML-CSS-and-other-languages http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120025/will-i-be-downvoted-for-giving-a-w3schools-link

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have a loop. Only a conditional statement. Use `while`.

```
var count = 1;
while( count < 1000 ) {
      count = count+1;
      console.log(count);
      setTimeout("startProgress", 1000); // you really want to do this 1000 times?
}
```

Better:

```
var count = 1;
setTimeout(startProgress,1000); // I'm guessing this is where you want this
while( count < 1000 ) {
    console.log( count++ );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Ken!

Comment: That did the trick, but the timeout isn't working...any idea?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to fire that off before the loop? Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, as I don't know what startProgress is supposed to be. I assume you mean that to be a function call?

Comment: As SLaks said, you *really* shouldn't be passing a string to `setTimeout`.

Comment: The call should be just be this, no strings: `setTimeout(startProgress,1000);`

Comment: Yup, made it not a string in the better example.

Comment: Thanks, Ken!  This is zooming to 100, any reason that the timeout wouldn't work?

Comment: The timeout is "pausing" before the startProgress is called, right?  I need a second pause between each increment of "count"...

Comment: Well, you're not doing anything inside the `while` loop other than incrementing and logging. You might take a look at @Nick's answer, where he guesses you may really be looking for `setInterval`. That will run a function repeatedly until you call `clearInterval`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `while` loop there:

```
var count = 0;
while(count < 1000) {
  count++;
  console.log(count);
  setTimeout("startProgress", 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers suggest, `if` vs `while` is your issue.  However, a better approach to this would be to use [`setInterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp), like this:

```
setinterval(startProcess, 1000);
```

This doesn't stop at 1000 calls, but I'm assuming you're just doing that for testing purposes at the moment.  If you do need to stop doing it, you can use [`clearInterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp), like this:

```
var interval = setinterval(startProcess, 1000);
//later...
clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what he's trying to do, but +1.